# MFC C++ - crashing on ProcessShellCommand() with no commands

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I am debugging the release build of my application, and have determined that an exception is occurring on `ProcessShellCommand`. Here is the relevant code.

```
ParseCommandLine(m_cmdInfo);
CString strDebug;
strDebug.Format(_T("%d"),m_cmdInfo.m_nShellCommand);
AfxMessageBox(strDebug);
if (!ProcessShellCommand(m_cmdInfo)) {
    return FALSE;
}
AfxMessageBox(_T("Done"));
```

The first message box successfully appears, but the second one doesn't. The exception that apparently occurs therefore must occur on `ProcessShellCommand()`. However, as you can see, the first message box is supposed to show the shell command, but it comes up empty! So I don't understand what `ProcessShellCommand()` is actually doing.

Can anyone offer some insight and/or suggestions? Thanks.

Debug of m_cmdInfo: http://i61.tinypic.com/mjbthh.jpg

Comment: `AfxMessageBox` requires a string but `m_nShellCommand` is an `enum` (then an integer). With an integer `AfxMessageBox` will try to use it as a resource ID...

Comment: If your program crashes, always run in in the debugger, it might not crash where you expect it to crash. For example, who says that it isn't the `AfxMessageBox` function that crashes when the message box is closing?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti thanks, I have changed the code as above and am now getting 0 in the popup. Not sure what that means..

Comment: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84dxkf0w.aspx). It's `FileNew` and it means: _"CCommandLineInfo::FileNew   Indicates that no file name was found on the command line."_

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Sorry yes, I did see that here :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84dxkf0w.aspx, wasn't sure what to take from that... Does that mean it's not getting the file I'm trying to run properly?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am running it from Visual Studio. If I run it in Debug mode I get a completely unrelated error before it even loads; it's a procedure entry point error on an imported dll.

Comment: It means in command line there isn't any file name. But it's pretty strange place for errors (especially if in release mode you get something completely different). I'd check for usage of some invalid pointer that corrupted memory somewhere (or something you didn't initialize properly and in debug mode you get an ASSERT).

Comment: In an attempt to be helpful I have screenshotted a debug of the m_cmdInfo value.. Not sure if that all looks okay

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Don't quite know where to go from there :S The weird thing is this all worked 2 days ago...

Comment: It doesn't really matter (IMO) what's inside there. If ProcessShellCommand() crashes application then _probably_ corruption is somewhere else. An access to an invalid pointer that corrupted something used by ProcessShellCommand(), for example. Problem is that it may has been done **anywhere BEFORE that call**.

Comment: You may also find the discussion in [MFC application crashing in ProcessShellCommand() when file to open specified on command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164837/mfc-application-crashing-in-processshellcommand-when-file-to-open-specified-on) of interest and helpfulness.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling CoInitialize(NULL) before that piece of code.

Or alternatively, try moving the code that opens the main window before this parsing.